# Вторая страница WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть страница магазина WooCommerce, на которую выводятся все категории и все товары из этих категорий. Нужно сделать вторую и третью страницу магазина с выводом других категорий и товаров. Вопрос как? В документации ничего не нашёл. Вывод происходит через код.

```
<div class="shop_menu">
                    <div class="shop_menu-title">Меню</div>
                    <div class="shop_menu-category">
                        <ul class="shop_menu-category_list clearfix">

                            <?php

                            $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
                            $orderby      = 'name';
                            $show_count   = 0;
                            $pad_counts   = 0;
                            $hierarchical = 1;
                            $title        = '';
                            $empty        = 0;
                            $args = array(
                                'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                                'orderby'      => $orderby,
                                'show_count'   => $show_count,
                                'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                                'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                                'title_li'     => $title,
                                'hide_empty'   => $empty
                            );

                            $categories = get_categories( $args );
                            if( $categories ){
                                foreach( $categories as $cat ){

                                    ?>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            }?>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ сделать страницу с товарами - использовать [шорткоды WooCommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/). Например:

```
[products limit="-1" columns="4" category="flowers, trees" cat_operator="OR"]
```

А код, который вы привели в вопросе, никуда не годится. Он не для WooCommerce. И выводит только список категорий, а не товары.